# java - server not recieving messages from client (reader.readLine() == null ?)

Tags: java, sockets, connection

so i've been making a simple chat, than has a server and a bunch of clients connected to them. On the client side i have class ConnectionManager to manage creating socket and such. Here is it's core method:

```
public class ConnectionManager {
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    public ConnectionManager(String URL, int port){
        tryConnectToServer(URL, port);
    }

    public BufferedReader getReader() {
        return reader;
    }

    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return writer;
    }
    private void tryConnectToServer(String ip, int servSocket) {
        try{
            socket = new Socket(ip, servSocket);
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            socket.getInputStream()));
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Unable to connect to specified server. Code pink");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Connection Manager object is a part of ChatGUI. ChatGUI's fields writer and reader are obtained and set from CM in order to pass writer along with ChatGUI's JTextField (msgInput) to SendButtonListener:

```
private void addSendButton() {
    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    sendButton.addActionListener(new SendButtonActionListener(writer, msgInput));
    panel.add(sendButton);
    panel.add(this.msgArea);
}
```

Then, actionPerformed method does:

```
public class SendButtonActionListener implements ActionListener{
private PrintWriter writer;
private JTextField msgInput;

public SendButtonActionListener(PrintWriter pr, JTextField mi){
    writer = pr;
    msgInput = mi;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    writer.println(msgInput.getText());
    System.out.println("Sending: " + msgInput.getText());
    flushMessageInputField();
}

private void flushMessageInputField(){
    msgInput.setText("");
}
```

}

On the server side on the other hand i've got this:

```
try{
        this.servSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server socket established");
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Unable to establish server socket. Code pink \n");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And after the above comes this:

```
public void waitForClients(){
    System.out.println("The gates has been opened...");
    while (true){
        try {
            Socket client = servSocket.accept();
            processClient(client);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void processClient(Socket client){
    writers.add(getClientWriter(client));
    startUpdateFrom(client);
    System.out.println("New client connected: " + client.getPort());
}

private PrintWriter getClientWriter(Socket client){
    try{
        return new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And finally, a new thread starts to listen to any new messages from that client:

```
private void startUpdateFrom(Socket client){
    new Thread(
            new WaitAndSendToAllFrom(client))
                .start();
}
```

Which is:

```
public class WaitAndSendToAllFrom implements Runnable{
    BufferedReader reader;

    public WaitAndSendToAllFrom(Socket clientSocket){
        try{
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            String message;
            System.out.println("Thread: waiting for messages to send...");
            while (true){
                message = reader.readLine();
                while (message != null){
                    System.out.println("Server: Sending message: " + message);
                    sendToAll(message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendToAll(String message){
        List<PrintWriter> writers = ServerClientConnector.getWriters();
        for (PrintWriter pr : writers){
            pr.println(message + "\n");
            pr.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

The cycle gets to the "Thread: waiting for messages to send...", but not any further, reader.readLine() returns null (checked with a sysout :) ). I was trying to debug it, but i'm not so experienced in programing so much, especially debugging two separate codes working with each other. I've been looking at this for 3 days, and i'm seriously stuck here.

Comment: Can you post the code that sends the message from the client as well? By the way, you have an endless loop in `WaitAndSendToAllFrom->run->while(message != null)` - there's no way that message changes within the while.loop so it will loop and loop forever (even if it isn't the problem you asked for, it could be the next one).

Comment: I've edited the post, not much was to write, but I believe that's all that is needed :). In advance for other bugs/errors - I know that code needs to be changed a lil bit and refactored, but for now I'm focusing on those damn sockets/readers/writers :).

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true){
    message = reader.readLine();
    while (message != null){
        System.out.println("Server: Sending message: " + message);
        sendToAll(message);
    }
}
```

This makes no sense. You read one line and then keep testing. It for null in a loop in which it can never change.

A proper way to write this is:

```
while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println("Server: Sending message: " + message);
    sendToAll(message);
}
```

Comment: I know, it was set this way just to check if the initial line at least get through. Before, I've had it the way you posted, but thought that maybe the problem lays in assigning readLine() outcome to message. I know it sounds foolish, but i was trying everything :)

Comment: Programmig doesn't consist of trying everything, and neither does anything else. You have to be analytic.